# BadRequestException: Invalid model identifier specified: Empty

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, terraform, aws-api-gateway, terraform-provider-aws

As shown in the screenshot, I wanted to add a content-type to my `aws_api_gateway_method_response`.

[image]

I tried this with Terraform:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_method_response" "response_200" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.id
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.api_resource.id
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.mymethod.http_method
  status_code = "200"

  response_models = {
       "application/json" = "Empty"
  }
}
```

However, I get an error with the response_models that:

```
BadRequestException: Invalid model identifier specified: Empty
```

Do I need to declare `Empty`somewhere?